# Grails unit/intergration testing

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, junit, spock

I'm trying to add unit-test and integration-test for my grails application but I have some trouble how to distinguish between both and when to use unit or integration to test my controllers actions and services.

The tutorial I found online is not very clean. I can't find complete example to follow up.

Can you please share helpful topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with integration tests is their speed. For me, integration tests take 15+ seconds to start up. In that time, certain things do slip out of mind focus.

I prefer to go with unit tests that start in no more then 2 sec and can be run several times in those 15 seconds.

One more argument for unit tests is they force you to decouple your code. Integration tests always tempt you to just rely on some other component existing and initialized.

Important links:
http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html
http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html

Comment: Thanks much for your reply. which grails version did you use ?
I'm starting with unit test to cover filter action.  I'm trying with 3.2.3 but I have some issues with one-to-many relation ship. when i do save then do search.

Comment: I did save(flush:true) and its correctly saved.
Then I do controller.search which I expect to return the above instance (count should be one). but I got the bellow exception because in this stage it could find the parent instance although I already saved(flush true) 
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Answer (score 1):

I follow the following guidelines:

- Try writing as many unit tests as you can. They can be written for controllers, services, domain classes or any other groovy classes. The idea is that unit tests are friends for developers. Writing enough unit tests will
  make sure that the developer makes lesser mistakes. As they execute
  quickly, this means quick verification. But unit tests cannot test the following:

  - Criteria queries, HQL queries
  - Actual database Interactions (queries, transactional behaviour, updates, db constraints etc.)
  - Inter modular interactions
    So we write the Integration tests as well
- Integration tests take longer to execute. Writing Integration tests often need bootstrapping data. But they really are helpful to test functionalities end to end (excluding the actual user interactions through UI for which functional tests are written). So Integration Tests can be written for:
- Testing all database interactions as unit tests actually do not test the database interactions. This also includes testing criteria, hql etc.,

  - Testing transactional behaviour (which is dependent on db)
  - Testing implementations end to end. So this will also test how two independently created modules interact with each other and make sure we have created them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not just a matter preference or speed. It is a huge subject, but I can give you some advice based on my experience.

If you expect to be covering your database access code (queries, transactional behaviour) by using unit tests, you are deluding yourself. You are testing how your queries comply with the in-memory implementation of GORM. Not hibernate, not your database.

I usually have two types of tests. Unit and functional tests. The functional tests will perform a full test, running against a real database, and stimulating the system like a user would (if it is a web site via Geb, if it is a REST api, via a REST client).

The functional tests will set up a startup state by executing some kind of fixture code first. This can be registering a user and logging them in, for example. Then the test will run, and then the postconditions are checked. Here, you can check the postconditions either by accessing the database through the GORM API, or by using production API calls (danger of covering a bug with another bug).
Sometimes, your system will interact with a third system. Here, if you can, you can mock the implementation of the third system, by injecting a mock implementation into the system under test.
You have also tools like Spring Cloud Contract, that allow you to create bock a mock server for your system under test, and a specification for your third-party system. See https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html

The unit tests, I use to thoroughly test all execution paths of a given class. I will try to trigger all exception states, all secondary scenarios, to make sure that everything is covered. I don't think it is realistic to have 100% coverage by using functional or integration tests.